# Erlang : flattening a list of strings

Tags: list, erlang, flatten

I have a list like this:

```
[["str1","str2"],["str3","str4"],["str5","str6"]]
```

And I need to convert it to

```
["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"]
```

How do I do this?

The problem is that I'm dealing with lists of strings, so when I do

```
lists:flatten([["str1","str2"],["str3","str4"],["str5","str6"]])
```

I get

```
"str1str2str3str4str5str6"
```

However, if the elements of the original list where just atoms, then `lists:flatten` would have given me what I needed. How do I achieve the same with strings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

lists:append does exactly what you need:

```
1> lists:append([["str1","str2"],["str3","str4"],["str5","str6"]]).
["str1","str2","str3","str4","str5","str6"]
```

(lists:concat does the right thing, but threatens to do some type conversion too.)

Answer (score 2):

If your list is always a "list of list of string", then you can simply use the `foldl` operator, with something like:

```
Flat = list:foldl(fun(X, Acc) -> X ++ Acc end, [], List)
```

In the case your list nesting can be of arbitrary depth, I would rather suggest to let erlang know your strings are not mere character lists, using an encoding such as:

```
[[{string, "str1"},{string, "str2"}],
 [{string, "str3"}, {string, "str4"}],
 [{string, "str5"},{string, "str6"}]]
```

This way, `list:flatten` will do the right thing, and give:

```
[{string, "str1"},{string, "str2"},
 {string, "str3"}, {string, "str4"},
 {string, "str5"},{string, "str6"}]
```

which you can convert back if needed to a raw list of strings using `foldl`.
If your strings are to be handled differently from mere character lists, then they probably deserve to be a real data structure, see this [blog entry](http://lethain.com/entry/2009/jul/24/distinguishing-strings-from-lists-in-erlang/) for an interesting discussion on this matter.

Comment: If you want a more generic approach you might want to have a look at io_lib:printable_list/1. i.e. only flatten if the list is not printable.

Comment: `list:foldl(fun erlang:'++'/2, [], List)` is even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

lists:concat/1 works...

Answer (score 0):

The reason lists:flatten doesn't work for you is that strings in Erlang are just lists of small integers.  We can handle this with a function that stops recursing down in a nested list if the list is just a string.

For arbitrarily nested list of strings you can use the following function:

```
slab([]) ->
    [];
slab([F|R]) ->
    case io_lib:char_list(F) of
        true -> [F|slab(R)];
        false -> slab(F) ++ slab(R)
    end.
```

It uses io_lib:char_list() to decide if the nesting recursion was deep enough.

Exampe of operation:

```
1> slab([[["foo", "bar"], "baz", [[[["foobar"]]]], "froboz", "the end"]]).
["foo","bar","baz","foobar","froboz","the end"]
2>
```

A small improvement that would make it possible to use mixed nested lists:

```
slab([]) ->
    [];
slab([F|R]) when is_list(F) ->
    case io_lib:char_list(F) of
        true -> [F|slab(R)];
        false -> slab(F) ++ slab(R)
    end;
slab([F|R]) ->
    [F|slab(R)].
```

This behaves just like lists:flatten except that it handles string as if they would be no lists:

```
1> slab([[["foo", "bar"], "baz", [[[["foobar", atom]],[a,b,c]]], 2, "froboz", "the end"]]).
["foo","bar","baz","foobar",atom,a,b,c,2,"froboz","the end"]
```